# Open external website in the webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How do I open external websites inside the webview used by phonegap. If I'm using

```
window.location.href = "www.example.com"
```

It will open the browser and load the website instead.

I found https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser but this will open a modal with the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `PhoneGap.plist` add under the `ExternalHosts` key: `*.example.com`. It's in fact a white list to prevent your application going to non-authorized url, otherwise it will open in the webbrowser which is kind of a sandbox environment.

Anyway I don't think it will work, if you leave the PhoneGap structure by going to an other url, in addition to the whitelist, you should use an iframe to handle external links.

EDIT: for Android open your config.xml file and add the following:

- To allow access to every domains: `<access origin="*" />`
- To a specific domain: `<access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />`

You can also check the [documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) of this file.

Comment: Didn't mention that I'm experiencing this problem on android, so I don't have a .plis file

Comment: Ok so on android, you should be able to use iframe directly since it is allowed by default, if it doesn't work then in your config.xml file add the following: `<access origin="*" />`

Comment: The Android equivalent white-list is the config.xml file that you should have in the res/xml folder.